# How to use a button in a method, or get this button working c#

Tags: c#, button

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication2
{

    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {

        public Form1()
        {

            InitializeComponent();
            decimal paint;
            decimal luxury = 1.75m;
            decimal standard = 1.00m;
            decimal economy = 0.45m;
            decimal undercoat;
            decimal a = numericUpDown1.Value;
            decimal b = numericUpDown2.Value;
            decimal c = numericUpDown3.Value;
            decimal d = numericUpDown4.Value;
            decimal totalLength = a + b + c + d;
            decimal height = numericUpDown5.Value;
            string Length = richTextBox3.Text = "The total length of the room is: " + (a + b + c + d).ToString();
            string totalArea = richTextBox4.Text = "The total area of the room is: " + (totalLength * height).ToString();
            decimal area = (a + b + c + d) * height;
            comboBox1.Items.Add("Luxury £1.75");
            comboBox1.Items.Add("Standard £1.00");
            comboBox1.Items.Add("Economy £0.45");
            comboBox2.Items.Add("Undercoat Paint £0.50");
            if (comboBox1.SelectedIndex == 0)
            {
                paint = luxury;

            }
            else if (comboBox1.SelectedIndex == 1)
            {
                paint = standard;
            }
            else if (comboBox1.SelectedIndex == 2)
            {
                paint = economy;
            }
            else
            {
                paint = 0;
            }


            if (comboBox2.SelectedIndex == 0)
            {
                undercoat = 0;
            }
            else if (comboBox2.SelectedIndex == 1)
            {
                undercoat = 0.50m;
            }
            else
            {
                undercoat = 0;
            }





            decimal total = area * paint * undercoat;
            string theTot = richTextBox5.Text = "Total cost is: £ " + total;


        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }
        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void richTextBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void richTextBox2_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }


        private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void numericUpDown1_ValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void numericUpDown4_ValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void numericUpDown3_ValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void numericUpDown2_ValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void richTextBox3_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void numericUpDown5_ValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void textBox1_TextChanged_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void richTextBox4_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void textBox3_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

    }
}
```

basically i am trying a button to work but the variables are not available for the button method, I have tried to make them global but other things seem to stop working. I want this button below to work along with the rest of the code.

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
string theTot = richTextBox5.Text = "Total cost is: £ " + total;
string Length = richTextBox3.Text = "The total length of the room is: " + (a + b + c + d).ToString();
            string totalArea = richTextBox4.Text = "The total area of the room is: " + (totalLength * height).ToString();

    }
```

Answer (score 1):

All of your variables are declared within the forms constructor, therefore their scope is limited to this, move them outside of the constructor

```
public class Form1
{
   string string1;
   string string2;

    public Form1()
    {
       //they are currrently here, move outside
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are declaring the variables in the constructor; move them to the root level of the class as such:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    private decimal paint;
    private decimal luxury = 1.75m;
    private decimal standard = 1.00m;
    private decimal economy = 0.45m;
    private decimal undercoat;
    private decimal a, b, c, d;
    .
    .
```

Then in the constructor, initialize the variables:

```
public Form1()
{
   InitializeComponent();
   a = numericUpDown1.Value;
   b = numericUpDown2.Value;
   c = numericUpDown3.Value;
   d = numericUpDown4.Value;
   totalLength = a + b + c + d;
   .
   .
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your variables are **not** declared on class level as opposed to what you said:

```
decimal a = numericUpDown1.Value;
decimal b = numericUpDown2.Value;
decimal c = numericUpDown3.Value;
decimal d = numericUpDown4.Value;
...
```

You can declare them on class level:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form 
{
    decimal a, b, c, d;

    ...
}
```

and can initialize them in `Form_Load` or better inside `button1_Click` to get most recent `a, b, c, d` etc. values from `NumericUpDown` controls:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    a = numericUpDown1.Value;
    b = numericUpDown2.Value;
    c = numericUpDown3.Value;
    d = numericUpDown4.Value;
    ...
}
```